# How to extract text from forms marked with enctype:multipart/form-data(JSF 2.0)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I have a JSF page that has a h:form that has some textfields and also an imageupload gadget from [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/)

My question is:
How can i get the text from the fields and assign them to some variable.(The objective is to separate the uploaded image/s from the text)

-What should i do?

-Do i need a filter, for that?

-Is there any easy way to achieve it with primefaces fileupload tool?

Comment: Which version of PrimeFaces is this? Is it 2.x or the 3.0 milestone releases?

Comment: I use 2.2.1 but but i would not mind to try the new 3.0, i just saw it came out :)

Comment: I do not know what happens in 3.0, but I know this is tough/impossible using 2.2.1. I attempted this a few days back, and decided not have any other widgets than the fileUpload component in my form. You might want to mix [BalusC's approach](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) with PrimeFaces, but I suspect it would take a deep understanding of the facelets lifecycle to achieve what you are attempting.

Comment: Most of the trouble lies with the fact that the PrimeFaces fileUpload component will send a separate multipart request that creates a FileUpload event that is queued and processed by the FileUploadListener declared in the tag. This request itself carries a value of `true` for a field `javax.faces.partial.ajax`, making it necessary to store the file temporarily, and also, it doesn't contain all the values in the form. Therefore, you will have to include a `submit` component in the form, so that a second (multipart) request with ordinary form values can be made. Or you can have a second form.

Comment: I understand, but i am really confused. Can just text be submited at all if the form is multipart? About the second form, i dont know how to do it, how will i organize the component, if one form is under the other(The upload gadet has other text fields above and below). Do you think it is possible to create a custom component component inside a normal form that has its own multipartform?(That could be a solution) I rode somewhere that there is a tool called subform. Do you know something about that?

Comment: I have the impression that your confusion is caused by ignorance of how HTTP works and how JSF/PrimeFaces "under the covers" works. You would need a good understanding of the basic HTTP spec (RFC 2616), multipart/form-data spec (RFC 2388) and the basic Java Servlet API (JSR 315). Investigating the HTTP request/response traffic using Firebug/Fiddler yourself should also clear a lot up. On w3c there's also a pretty clear explanation about HTML form content types: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial with PrimeFaces 2.2.1. The PF 2 file upload handling is a bit an epic fail. Under the covers it's already not trivial to upload files with Ajax. The `XMLHttpRequest` object simply doesn't support `multipart/form-data` requests. Lot of "Ajaxified" (to have the feeling of an asynchronous progress) file upload solutions are based on a hidden iframe or -as in case of PF- using Flash. The PF 2 one is based on Flash and this is not combinable with regular text inputs in order to submit all the data in one go.

In PF 3 the file upload component has been [greatly revised](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadHome.jsf). Using "simple" file upload mode your problem should be solved. However, PF 3 is currently still in beta/alpha stage. You would need to do a lot of unit tests on your webapp to see if it doesn't break on PF 3.

If PF 3 is not an option, then your best bet is using Tomahawk 2.0 or homebrewing a JSF component.

- [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload/5424229#5424229) - Tomahawk 2.0 file upload tutorial
- [Uploading files with JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-with-jsf-20-and-servlet.html) - Custom file upload component tutorial

---

As to the filter, under the covers the `FacesServlet` uses [`HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the submitted values. When you're familiar with basic [JSP/Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), you should know how this usually works. The default HTML form encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The `getParameter()` method is relying on this. However, to be able to send binary data along this, such as file uploads, this default form encoding is [unsuitable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). For this `multipart/form-data` should be used instead.

However, with this form encoding the `getParameter()` calls won't work anymore then. They will all return `null`. At its simplest form, you would need to parse the request body manually on a per-request basis. See also [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) However, this doesn't work out in combination with JSF as it is relying on `getParameter()` calls in order to set the bean properties (model values) with submitted values and to invoke the command button/link action.

So you would like to change the `HttpServletRequest` that way so that the `getParameter()` calls returns the proper values. For that a `Filter` is the right choice as it runs *before* any servlet such as the `FacesServlet`. The filter should then parse the `multipart/form-data` request body, create a parameter map and wrap and replace the original `HttpServletRequest` with a custom implementation which returns the right parameters and pass that request object instead through the chain so that JSF can use it fully transparently "the usual way".

Comment: I will study this deeply until i understand it correctly. But one thing that still have doubt is: So it is possible for a form to submit, both textfield data and images in one click? What is needed is to parse that request appropiately right?

Comment: That's correct. Follow either the Tomahawk or custom component tutorial carefully and it should work (don't forget to **remove** the PrimeFaces upload filter from `web.xml` as it may collide!)

Comment: I think the second part of this answer should be updated, since `request.getParameter()` works fine to retrieve text fields form a multipart request, on any Servlet 3.0 container. (As stated here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237994/does-request-getparameter-still-work-when-uploading-files-with-servlet-3-0)