# Does request.getParameter() still work when uploading files with Servlet 3.0?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

I just read [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) from BalusC about how to upload files with the 3.0 Servlet API.

My question is about the use of `request.getParameter()` for common fields. For example, if my form looks like this :

```html
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="description">File description:</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="" />

        <label for="uploadedFile">File:</label>
        <input type="file" id="uploadedFile" name="uploadedFile" />

        <input type="submit" value="Send" />              
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Following what BalusC explained, I should manipulate the InputStream returned by `part.getInputStream()` to get the content of the **description** field. Why is that ? I tried to simply call `request.getParameter("description")`, and it seems to work fine.

I use Tomcat 7.0.20.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I tried to simply call request.getParameter("description"), and it seems to work fine.*

Indeed, this is specified as such in the Servlet 3.0 spec, but this did not work in earlier versions of Glassfish until recently, even though it's the reference implementation. This has been reported as [Glassfish issue 16740](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16740) and has been fixed in 3.1.2, more than 2 years after the first 3.0 release.

Comment: My bad, I should have tried on GlassFish or another server before asking... Apart the lack of specification, any idea why this is not implemented on other servers? It eases the task.

Comment: I can't disagree you. It definitely eases the task. I have 2 years ago also posted an enhancement request to the Servlet 3.0 spec. Maybe it's in Servlet 3.1.

Comment: @BaluC This feature should be available in all containers since Servlet 3.0.

Comment: @Ramesh: you're right! I was blindly basing on the behaviour of Glassfish, the reference implementation. It namely doesn't support it. That seems thus a bug in Glassfish.

Answer (score 3):

It is available since Servlet 3.0 itself. All Servlet 3.0 containers should make the input type parameters available through `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`.

This is what the [Servlet 3.0 Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) says on page 23:

> ### 3.2 File upload
>
> ...
>
> For parts with `form-data` as the `Content-Disposition`, but without a
>   filename,  the string value of the part will also be available via the
>   `getParameter` /  `getParameterValues` methods on `HttpServletRequest`,
>   using the name of the  part.

Comment: Indeed, I just checked the specs too. So in the end, who's to blame? Why is this part of the specs not implemented everywhere? Usually, it's Tomcat that lacks stuff, not the others. I'm lost! :)

Comment: I think all server's should implement it.